# Zabbix with active checks

Tags: linux, zabbix, zabbix-agent

In Zabbix 2.0 I have configured zabbix agents to be active and disabled passive checks.

I've also configured the host to automatically add these hosts to the "Discovered Hosts" host group.

However, the agent then still tries to connect to the agents despite active checks being disabled in the agents.  This results in "zabbix agent on [host] unreachable for 5 minutes" warnings.

I don't see an option in the host configuration to turn off those passive checks.  How is this done so as to remove these warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer eventually.

It seems creating a full clone of the template `Template App Zabbix Agent` to a new Template
`Template App Zabbix Agent Active`.

Then in the 3 items linked to this new cloned template

- Agent ping
- Host name of zabbix_agentd running
- Version of zabbix_agent(d) running"

Change the type field for each item from `Zabbix agent` to `Zabbix agent (active)`
and save each one.

I then created another cloned template `Template OS Linux Active` and changed the linked template to the new one `Template App Zabbix Agent Active`.

Now when this new template `Template OS Linux Active` is linked to my hosts they correctly gather data without complaint about not being able to connect to the zabbix agent.

Comment: Having the two templates allows me to have both active and passive checks available as I still have some hosts with passive checking.  If you wanted just active checks you could change the original template rather than cloning it.

Comment: In fact you have to go right through the template and ensure that zabbix agent (active) is checked for each item.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is still valid several years later.

To amplify, you have to go thru and change everything in the template to active. 
I created new templates with the active name appended.

Then do a search and replace for:
0 => 7

This will switch the item type to Zabbix Agent Active. 
You can do it the web UI, but you have to do it in a couple of places and it is not straightforward. Item prototypes tend to get missed when updating thru the web page.

Comment: It is still valid in my 3.4 . Do you mean you had to access zabbix database directly? Can you show us the sql query for this replace?